# Google Apps Script HTML form won't submit for overseas user

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a small sidebar form that submits user data.  It is all functional for anyone in the USA but if someone from overseas tries to submit the form, it fails.  I even logged into the same user account as the one overseas and the form submits for me.  I have never encountered an issue like this with GAS.  The account the user is logged into owns the spreadsheet that the script is housed in and he has tried both local and US IP addresses to submit the data (not sure if this even matters.)  What do I need to change/include in my scripts to allow all users to be able to submit the form?  Would creating a Webapp and trigger be a fix?

Code.gs

```
//OPEN THE FORM IN SIDEBAR 
function showFormInSidebar() {      
  
  var form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate().setTitle('New Client');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(form);
  
}

//PROCESS FORM DATA
function processForm(formObject){ 
  
  var notes = [formObject.client,
               formObject.website,
               formObject.email,
               formObject.plan];
  
  var mTabs = [formObject.client,
               formObject.plan,
               formObject.timeAllowed,
               '',
               '',
               '00:00:00.000'];
  
  pushToSheets(notes,mTabs);
  
}

//INCLUDE HTML PARTS, EG. JAVASCRIPT, CSS, OTHER HTML FILES
function include(filename) {
  
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
  
}


//THIS FUNCTION IS USED TO PUSH DATA TO EACH RESPECTIVE SHEET FROM THE SIDEBAR FORM SUBMISSION
function pushToSheets(notes,mTabs) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var noteTab = ss.getSheetByName('NOTES');
  var sheetArr = ['JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEPT','OCT','NOV','DEC'];
  //  var sheetArr = ['JAN','FEB'];
  var nLast = noteTab.getLastRow();
  noteTab.insertRowBefore(nLast+1);
  noteTab.getRange(nLast+1, 1,1,4).setValues([notes]);
  noteTab.getRange(2,1,nLast+1,17).sort([{column: 4, ascending: true}, {column: 1, ascending: true}])
  
  for(var x = 0; x < sheetArr.length; x++) {
    
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetArr[x]);
    var sLength = sheet.getLastRow();
    sheet.insertRowBefore(sLength-1);
    sheet.getRange(sLength-1, 1,1,6).setValues([mTabs]);
    sheet.getRange(2, 1,sLength,11).sort([{column: 2, ascending: true}, {column: 1, ascending: true}])
    
  }
  
}
```

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?> <!-- See JavaScript.html file -->
    <title>Contact Details</title>
  </head>
  
  <body class="bg-secondary text-light">
    <div class="container">
      <?!= include('Form'); ?> <!-- See Form.html file -->
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script>
  $('#timeAllowed').keypress(function() {
   
  var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]");
  var key = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
  if (!regex.test(key)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
   }
   
    if(this.value.length == 2){
        this.value = this.value+':';
     }
     
    if(this.value.length == 5){
        this.value = this.value+':00';
     }
     
     if(this.value.length > 7) {
            
        return false;
     
     }
});
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Form.html

```
 <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="client">Client</label>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" class="form-control" id="clint" name="client" placeholder="Client Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="gender">Plan</label>
    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="plan" name="plan" required>
      <option value="" selected disabled>Choose...</option>
      <option value="00 hosting">00 hosting</option>
      <option value="01 slim">01 slim</option>
      <option value="02 basic">02 basic</option>
      <option value="10 special">10 special</option>
      <option value="99 coming up">99 coming up</option>
      
      
    </select>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="last_name">Time Allowed</label>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" class="form-control" pattern="[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]" title ="00:00:00" id="timeAllowed" name="timeAllowed" placeholder="00:00:00">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="website">Website</label>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" class="form-control" id="website" name="website">
  </div>
  
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript.html

```
<script>
  // Prevent forms from submitting.
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
    
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);    
      
      
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: How does it fail?  Is there an error message?

Comment: @James it's weird...in the executions, it says it fails but when I try to open it up to see the details, it won't open...is there another way to find that data?

Comment: Without an error message it's impossible to tell... What are the web app's execution settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to add this as a Webapp and that fixed the issue.  Thank you for the suggestions!

```
//OPEN THE FORM IN SIDEBAR 
function showFormInSidebar() {      
  var form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('test').evaluate().setTitle('New Client');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(form);
}


function doGet() {
  var form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate().setTitle('New Client');
  form.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  return form;
}
```

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <center>
    <embed type="text/html" src="redacted"  width="290" height="800">
  </center>
  </body>
</html>
```